# My code won't build for some reason in cLion

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ellenorzes(int sz,int tomb[],int meret);
void kiir(int szamok[],int meret);

int main() {
    printf("Nem egyformak\n\n");

    int n,i=0,szam,tomb[100];
    printf("Hany veletlen szamot szeretnel?(max 100) ");
    do{
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n>100)
            printf("max 100\n");
    }while(n>100);

    while (i!=(n-1)){
        srand(time(0));
        szam=rand()%1000+1;
        if (ellenorzes(szam,tomb,i)){
            tomb[i]=szam;
            i++;
        }
    }
    kiir(tomb,i);

    return 0;
}

bool ellenorzes(int sz,int tomb[],int meret){
    for (int i=0;i!=meret;i++){
        if (sz==tomb[i])
            return false;
        i--;
    }
    return true;
}

void kiir(int szamok[],int meret){
    printf("A tomb elemei:");
    for (int i=0;i!=meret;i++)
        printf(" %d",szamok[i]);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
====================[ Build | _egyforma | Debug ]===============================

/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build "/Users/zombi170/Documents/Munka/BME/Tantárgyak/1. félév/Prog 1/Programok/:egyforma/cmake-build-debug" --target _egyforma -- -j 3
CMakeFiles/_egyforma.dir/build.make:70: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_egyforma.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_egyforma.dir/rule] Error 2

make: *** [_egyforma] Error 2
```

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the makefile, not the C code.

Comment: Try to update your `Makefile` by running `cmake .` in the project directory.
If it does not work, there's probably something wrong with `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: 2 notes: you should put `srand(time(0));` before the loop and you should also check if the entered value is negative